# PHP Display images in columns

Tags: php, html, css, image, gallery

I recently had an image gallery displayed nicely in four equally wide boxes, with the images as 100% width, clear both and height auto. This worked pretty well, except I had hundreds of images called on the page.

I am trying to get the same effect, only using a short php script to call the images and display them.

[Here is a link to the gallery before](http://kingdomworldbuffet.co.uk/gallery.html)

[And here is a link to the site which I am trying to achieve the 4 column fetch thing on.](http://toladverts.co.uk/balloonatics/gallery.php)

And the php code I currently have

```
<?php 
    $dir    = 'images/gallery/';
    $files  = scandir($dir);
    $images = array();

    foreach($files as $file) 
    {
        if(fnmatch('*.jpg',$file)) 
        {
            $images[] = $file;
        }
    }

    foreach($images as $image) 
    {
        echo '<img src="images/gallery/'.$image.'" />';
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this code

```
  $dir    = 'images/gallery/';
    $files  = scandir($dir);
    $images = array();


    foreach($files as $file) 
    {
        if(fnmatch('*.jpg',$file)) 
        {
            $images[] = $file;
        }
    }

    $image_count = count($images);
    $count_each_column = ceil($image_count/4);

    echo '<div style="width:100%; max-width:950px; margin:0 auto;">';
    $count = 0;
    foreach($images as $image) 
    {
        $count+=1;
        if($count==1)
        {
            echo '<div class="box boxgallery">';
        }

            echo '<img src="images/gallery/'.$image.'" />';

        if($count>=$count_each_column)
        {
            $count=0;
            echo '</div>';
        }
    }

    if($count>0)
    {
        echo '</div>';
    }
    echo '</div>';
```

and Some **CSS**

```
<style>
.boxgallery {
    margin: 0 0.6% 0 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 24%;
    float:left;
}

.boxgallery img {
    clear: both;
    float: left;
    height: auto;
    margin-bottom: 2%;
    transition: opacity 0.3s ease 0s;
    width: 100%;
}

</style>
```

Comment: Bravo! That's nailed it, thank you. 
[link](http://toladverts.co.uk/balloonatics/gallery.php)

Comment: Is there a way to fix the height issue of the columns? See previous link and this [link](http://toladverts.co.uk/balloonatics/gallery.php) @satish-sharma