# Fill a dynamic image grid vertically, and window width sensitive, is this possible?

Tags: php, jquery

[image: example of what I mean, total number of images are dynamic!]

This is what I'm after: I want a dynamic number of images, that I retrieve from a mysql database, placed in a grid that stretched out over the full window width, and is also vertically arranged! Currently it looks like this:

http://www.samweerdmeester.nl/main/main.php

I'm using standard css floats for the divs, resulting in a horizontally growing grid, but that should be vertically, so I need image 2, placed underneath image 1, not next to it, and 3 underneath 2, and so on ...

I could manage to do this when the number of columns was fixed, but the number of columns should be responsive to window width (when re-sizing browser) 
What IS constant is the image size, that's 200x200px always.

It this doable? Is there some PHP solution? I figured I could place each image in a div and calculate number of required columns by dividing the current window-width by total amount of images, and position each div vertically and horizontally, using some math in a loop.

But how to get this responsive to browser-resizing continuously?

Or am I taking a unnecessary difficult road, and is there some easy html solution.. tables maybe which I hardly ever use?

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23805015/php-display-images-in-columns might help you.

Comment: thanks I will check that one out, any other advice also more than welcome!